# How to specify Samba network adapter

Tags: wireless, networking, samba, shared-folders

This question might sound crazy, and maybe it is. My folder share can only be accessed through the ip address which corresponds to my wireless adapter. If someone tried to access the share through the ip address which corresponds to the wired adapter, they won't see it.

I have a samba share set up like the following:

```
[MyShare]
    path = /media/MyShare
    available = yes
    writeable = yes
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0755
```

The global section contains

```
wins support = yes
```

Recently I have had to disable my wireless adapter. Unfortunately, there is no longer a way to access this share. I was under the impression samba would allow access through any network connection. Does anyone know the reason for this behavior? Do I need to explicitly tell Samba which IP address or network adapter it should be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify which adapter samba can bind :

in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

add the following under global section :

```
[global]
    interfaces =  ( choose your adapter maybe wlan0 )
    bind interfaces only = yes
```

The interface you write will be used by samba , you can specify more than one Adapter.

Comment: What's the syntax to add more than one interface? It looks like I can only access the network over LAN, and not any WiFi network.

Comment: @NoVa Add them separated by space: interfaces = wlan0 eth0 lo